# Multiple categorical variables transform to dummy

Tags: regression, binary-data, linear, categorical-encoding, many-categories

I'm developing a linear regression model that contains multiple categorical explanatory variables (e.g., cities, marital status), including other binary and continous variables.
The output is 0/1 variable. Later, I will be run through backwards elimination, to pick the best model.
My thought was to transform the categorical variables into dummies.

My question is whether I can include all the dummy variables -1 in each category (to avoid the dummy trap). Is this the right way to do it?

Or can I only inlcude 1 of the dummy variables (e.g. New York and Married) from the categorical variable, which I know have significantly high correlation with the output compared to other cities and marital status?

Comment: Does this help https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/388049/one-hot-encoding-gives-untractable-amount-of-classes/388051#388051 ?

Comment: Thank you, @Tim. This unfortunately does not seem to be the answer I'm looking for. I'm wondering if I have multiple cateogrical variables in a model, how can I interperate this in a regression, and also avoid the dummy trap?