# How to interpret feature hashing ouptut?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, classification, categorical-data, feature-selection

I am working on a binary classification problem with 1000 rows but have multiple high cardinality variables.

So, I decided to use Hash encoder to avoid curse of dimensionality.

However, after feeding in my columns as shown below,

```
    encoder = ce.HashingEncoder(cols=['market', 'Segment', 'Application',
           'Product Classification','State', 'Pincode'
           'Project Status','Country','line', 'DIV'], return_df=True)
categorical_data_transformed = encoder.fit_transform(categorical_data)
```

I got an output like below

[image]

My questions are

a) How do I know which hash value corresponds to what category or column?

b) How do I get the column names? `instead of col1, col2, col3 etc`?

c) How do we use this if we wish to explain our predictions to business users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*You don’t.* It uses [hashing trick](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/388049/one-hot-encoding-gives-untractable-amount-of-classes/388051#388051), so the data is passed through a hashing function that maps the data to codes. The function can and will map different values to same codes, because in general it is used to reduce cardinality of your data. To learn what values were mapped to what codes, you need to create a dictionary by looping over your data, transforming it, and saving the *input $\to$ output* pairs for all the unique inputs. The mappings are meaningless, so you can’t interpret them. In terms of explainability it is a classical black box.

Comment: thanks, upvoted. So, hashing may not be a good approach if we are interested in explaining the predictions to business users? Meaning, we don't know which feature has which values leads to prediction 1

Comment: is there any other approach that you suggest for feature encoding ? (other than one hot encoding) because I have high cardinality variables

Comment: @TheGreat see the linked thread for many solutions.